# Ruby strftime '%-m' not working in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, strftime

My goal is to query Items by their user_id, year created, and month created. I am using sqlite3 in development and postresql in production on Heroku.

I want to do something like this:

```
items.where("user_id = '?' AND strftime('%Y', created_at) = '?' AND strftime('%-m', created_at) = '?' ", 6, 2015, 3)
```

But it returns no records.

This works:

```
items.where("user_id = '?' AND strftime('%Y', created_at) = '?' ", 6, 2015)
```

But this returns no records:

```
items.where("user_id = '?' AND strftime('%-m', created_at) = '?' ", 6, 3)
```

Am I using the `'%-m'` format incorrectly?

Comment: Don't use quotes for `?`. It may be excusable with SQLite3; not in general. What is `%-m` format? I've never seen it, and can't find it in the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). (Note: you are writing SQL, so it is SQLite3 `strftime`, not Ruby `strftime`.)

Comment: Note that `strftime` is an SQLite-ism to work around the lack of native time types, that won't work at all with PostgreSQL. Do yourself a favor and install PostgreSQL locally so that you can develop, test, and deploy with the same database.

Comment: Is there a good reason you're not using postgresql in development? Surely an issue like this highlights why it can be really useful to use the same technology across all of your environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use different databases in development and production, use the same one. Just configure postgresql on your localhost and change your query to something like:

```
user.items.where("date_part('year', created_at) = :year AND date_part('month', created_at) = :month", year: 2015, month: 6)
```

That's assuming that you have the associations setup between items and users, then you don't need to query on `user_id` as well.